# should I worry about this "Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock" error?

Tags: samba4

I have a samba server mounted to `/srv/smb`. Wanted to check on the filesystem using tune2fs I ran into an error which I don't understand and wonder whether it is something to worry about

```
$ tune2fs -l /srv/smb/
tune2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
tune2fs: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /srv/smb/
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine.

`tune2fs` only knows about ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystems. If you use it on something else, like a Samba share, you get an error like this because `tune2fs` can't deal with it.

Comment: right. once I replace /srv/samba (which is the mount point) with the device (/dev/sdb1) it works like a charm. thanks